# Pass class properties as values to method parameters

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have

```
class A {
    private $_property = 'string';

    public function method($property=$this->_property) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It doesn't let me do it.

The reason I want to do it is (maybe bad practice but still...):

1. I want the default value of property to be 'string' in each method in this class, but I don't want `public function method($property='string')` because if I need to change it, I have to do it in every method
2. I want to pass the parameter when instantiating the class and using this method, so lately I will need `$class = new A(); $param = 'string2'; $class->method($param);`
3. Since `$_property` is private, I cannot change its value
4. If I do:

```
class A {
    private $_property = 'string';

    public function method($property) {
        $property = $this->_property;
    }
}
```

It doesn't let me to change the param from outside. I mean, it's always 'string', no matter the code from point 2.

Is there anyway to achieve the point from the first quoted code, without making the property public, neither assigning inside the method, the value of the param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter default values need to be static because they need to be evaluated at compile time. If you'd make the class property `static` you could use it, but that may not be what you want.

The easiest way is probably:

```
public function method($property = null) {
    $property = $property ?: $this->_property;
    ...
}
```

(Uses PHP 5.3's shorthand `?:` operator.)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a const in my class :

```
class A {
    const _property = 'string';

    public function method($property = self::_property) {
        echo $property;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like that:

```
Class A {

private $_property = 'string';

public function method($property=null) {
    if($property == null)
        $property = $this->_property;
}
```

It will simulate what you need. When you dont send any param it will take default one from your class.